# Looping over Ember JS Model in Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Is there a short hand way to loop over all the property keys, values and types in a model instance in ember js handlebars template.

For example wanting to do something like this in the template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each key, value, type in model}}
    <li> <span class="label label-info">{{key}}</span>: {{value}} is a {{type}} </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Maybe this is just not possible with handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of something that might work for you:

https://gist.github.com/strathmeyer/1371586

Answer (score 2):

As far I know this is not possible as you already guessed.
The only way I could think of would be to write your own `each` helper that supports this kind of loop. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/) for a starting point on that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, a helper method makes sense. But do you know of a dynamic way to either get all the property keys of a model or otherwise get all properties of a model programmatically? Maybe this is buried in some API documentation somewhere but I can't find it.